# what is the cheapest way for sending ethereum from 10 account addresses to 10 account addresses?

Tags: transactions, ether, transfer, eoa, smart-contract-wallets

What is the cheapest way to send ether to 10 addresses? By using smart contract or using externally owned account to send one by one...? I know that the gas limit of a normal transaction is 21,000...so 10 of this transaction costs 210,000 gas. I think send ether to 10 addresses by using smart contract has cost more than 210,000 gas, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10 transactions from an EOA will cost 210,000 gas.

The most efficient way to do this would be to deploy a contract that accepts funds in the constructor and subsequently distributes the funds to 10 different addresses. This will cost the initial 21,000 gas, plus the cost of the transfers, which is maybe ~100,000.

Comment: thanks for your answering...the contract that you described transfer the funds In an instant? or  contract can hold funds until 10  address send ether to contract and then transfer them to 10 address?

Comment: if you have a good refrence for this type of contract please share with me @Shane Fontaine